# Attach suffixes to PySpark rows

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a PySpark dataframe with two columns `A` and `B`. Each of these columns are of string datatype.

Following is an example of the dataframe

```
|-------|-------|
|   A   |   B   |
|-------|-------| 
| "a1"  |  "b1" |
| "a2"  |  "b2" |
| "a3"  |  "b3" |
| "a4"  |  "b4" |
| "a5"  |  "b5" |
| "a6"  |  "b6" |
|-------|-------|
```

**I want to affix the tags `_1` , `_2` and `_3` at random chosen rows to create two new columns `A1` and `B1`** such that the dataframe is now like the following:

```
|-------|-------|---------|---------|
|   A   |   B   |    A1   |    B1   |
|-------|-------|---------|---------| 
| "a1"  |  "b1" | "a1_1"  |  "b1_1" |
| "a2"  |  "b2" | "a2_2"  |  "b2_2" |
| "a3"  |  "b3" | "a3_1"  |  "b3_1" |
| "a4"  |  "b4" | "a4_3"  |  "b4_3" |
| "a5"  |  "b5" | "a5_3"  |  "b5_3" |
| "a6"  |  "b6" | "a6_2"  |  "b6_2" |
|-------|-------|---------|---------|
```

Here are a few rules that I need to take care of

- Whenever a given suffix (`_1` , `_2` or `_3`) is attached to the end of a row in `A`, the same suffix is attached to the end of the same row in `B` also.
- The numbers of times the suffixes feature should be same (or almost the same). In this example, we have three suffixes (`_1` , `_2` or `_3`) and each suffix features two times.
- The rows to which a given suffix is attached is chosen randomly.

**I would like a solution which works for the aforementioned example. How can I do this using PySpark?** In my actual dataframe, I expect to see close to a million rows and about 5 suffixes. So, an efficient solution will be really great here.

Comment: How precise must "almost the same" be? Can you just draw at random which suffix to use? `import random; rdd=rdd.map(lambda t: suffix='_'+str(random.randrange(3)); (t[0], t[1], t[0]+suffix, t[1]+suffix))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

# rand * 3 + 1 to give random numbers in (1,2,3)
df = df.withColumn("rand", (F.rand() * F.lit(3) + F.lit(1)).cast("int"))

a1 = F.concat(
    F.col("A"),
    F.lit("_"),
    F.col("rand")
).alias("A1")

b1 = F.concat(
    F.col("B"),
    F.lit("_"),
    F.col("rand")
).alias("B1")

df = df.select("A", "B", a1, b1)
```